# htacces apache v2.4

Tags: apache, .htaccess, prestashop

Tengo un fichero `.htaccess` propio de prestashop, con el siguiente contenido:

```
<FilesMatch "\.tpl$">
Deny from all
</FilesMatch>
```

El tema es que este fichero parece dar problemas con la nueva versión de apache v2.4 (la cual me provee mi hosting), y no funciona si lo utilizamos.

Es la primera vez que tengo un error con la configuración de un `.htaccess` y no encuentro ningún tipo de documentación, en lo relacionado a los ficheros `.htaccess` ni tampoco ningún usuario que se haya encontrado con algo parecido.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En la documentación de Apache hay un [artículo sobre la actualización de Apache 2.2 a 2.4](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/upgrading.html), en el que se encuentra una [sección específica para el tema de la autorización](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/upgrading.html#authz) y cómo algunas directivas (las que usas) cambian de una versión a la otra.

Lo que en Apache 2.2 era:

```
<FilesMatch "\.tpl$">
Deny from all
</FilesMatch>
```

En Apache 2.4 debería ser:

```
<FilesMatch "\.tpl$">
Require all denied
</FilesMatch>
```

Comment: Efectivamente ese era el problema, me apunto los dos enlaces que me has facilitado, para estudiarlos en pudiente, ya que me parece que van a ser el pan nuestro de cada día. Muchas gracias

Comment: Genial... Y buena suerte; los cambios en el servidor y .htaccess siempre me han resultado algo complejos. Espero que no necesites esos enlaces demasiado.